# encoding conversion tool

Tags: encoding

I would need some file encoding conversion tool, to convert some of my source files. I would need to do it as a batch, so the program needs to know to find out what's the source file encoding (Unicode - Codepage 1200) and save it as proper encoding (UTF-8), because project files are saved in different encodings.
Can someone suggest me a good free tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)

Comment: tried, though it doesn't list Unicode - Codepage 1200, which seems really strange